# Haskell lists sum triples

Tags: haskell

```
sumTriplos :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => [(a,b,c)] -> (a,b,c)
```

I want a function that sums all the triples in a list and returns one with all the sums like this :

```
sumTriplos [(2,4,11), (3,1,-5), (10,-3,6)] = (15,2,12)
```

code :

```
extractFirst :: (a, b, c) -> a 
extractFirst (a,,) = a 

extractSirst :: (a, b, c) -> a 
extractSirst (,a,) = a 

extractTirst :: (a, b, c) -> a 
extractTirst (,,a) = a 

sumTriplos :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => [(a,b,c)] -> (a,b,c) 
sumTriplos [(a,b,c)] = (a,b,c) 
sumTriplos (h:a:t) = sumTriplos ((extractFirst h)+(extractFirst a),(extractSirst h)+(extractSirst a),(extractTirst h)+(extractTirst a)) t
```

Comment: What particular problem are you having in writing such a function?

Comment: i wrote this : extractFirst :: (a, b, c) -> a
extractFirst (a,_,_) = a

extractSirst :: (a, b, c) -> a
extractSirst (_,a,_) = a

extractTirst :: (a, b, c) -> a
extractTirst (_,_,a) = a

sumTriplos :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => [(a,b,c)] -> (a,b,c)
sumTriplos [(a,b,c)] = (a,b,c)
sumTriplos (h:a:t) = sumTriplos ((extractFirst h)+(extractFirst a),(extractSirst h)+(extractSirst a),(extractTirst h)+(extractTirst a)) t

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: extractFirst :: (a, b, c) -> a extractFirst (a,,) = a extractSirst :: (a, b, c) -> a extractSirst (,a,) = a extractTirst :: (a, b, c) -> a extractTirst (,,a) = a sumTriplos :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => [(a,b,c)] -> (a,b,c) sumTriplos [(a,b,c)] = (a,b,c) sumTriplos (h:a:t) = sumTriplos ((extractFirst h)+(extractFirst a),(extractSirst h)+(extractSirst a),(extractTirst h)+(extractTirst a)) t

Comment: im sry i paste the wrong code but now is wright.

Comment: Again, edit your *question* with your code; don't put it in a comment, where it is barely readable.

Comment: i dont know ho to do it

Comment: There should be an "edit" link you can click just below the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sumTriplos` takes a single argument, a list. Your recursive call, though, is given *two* arguments, the sum of the first two tuples and the remaining tuples. You want to add the first tuple to the *result* of the recursive call on the remaining tuples.

Instead of (with the `extract*` functions abbreviated)

```
sumTriplos (h:a:t) = sumTriplos ((ef h + ef a), (es h + es a), (et h + et a)) t
```

you want something like

```
sumTriplos (h:t) = (ef h + ef r, es h + es r, et h + et r)
    where r = sumTriplos t
```

Comment: terminal : (*** Exception: fichas.hs:(149,1)-(150,26): Non-exhaustive patterns in function sumTriplos)

Answer (score 1):

a simple fold?

```
sumTriplos = foldr sumt (0,0,0) 
   where sumt (x,y,z) (a,b,c) = (x+a,y+b,z+c)
```

Comment: yeah but i want to sum a list of triples not just two

Comment: did you try with your list input?  `sumTriplos [(...`

Comment: @PedroNovais That's what `foldr` does. It starts with a current answer of `(0,0,0)`, then applies `sumt` to a list item and the current answer to get a new answer, until it was consumed the entire list, at which point the current answer is the final answer.

Comment: yeah but this is one of the questions for my test and i cant use foldr

Comment: no ahah i have this questions to prepare for my test

Comment: Then, you have to write your own recursive `fold` function to iterate over the list and add the elements to the running sum.